# Anyone know where to find the -(void)lock in iOS 7 so I can hook into it?

Tags: ios, ios7, header, jailbreak, springboard

As stated, I am trying to figure out what header in the iOS 7 Springboard that holds -(void)lock{

In earlier versions of iOS there was a SBAwayController that held this, but Apple apparently has decided to change the way it does things again... I have scoured threw the SB headers for hours and hours and have come up with a whole lot of nothing.  I did however find some other interesting things like how to make the screen flash with any given color or how to bring the user back to the lockscreen.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated thank you!!!

Comment: Have you checked SBLockScreenViewController?

Comment: Please describe what exactly do you want to achieve in result (like, for example, you want to hook into method which is called when screen is locked). Telling that something stopped working doesn't help us solving your problem.

Comment: @twodayslate yes I did look in there but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: @creker yes the is the method I am looking to hook into.  When the screen is locked